# Swipe Left to go Back

Tags: ios, css, onsen-ui

With OnsenUI 1.10, is there a way to swipe left to go to the previous page?

With OnsenUI, the app can look very native, however, the swipe-left iOS 7 gesture is important for my user experience.

I saw this: http://www.idangero.us/framework7/dist/ where the user can swipe left to go to the previous page. (On a desktop environment, you can drag from left to right)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use Hammer included in Onsen UI.
You can trap the gesture and do actions.
For example,

```
 ons.bootstrap();
 Hammer(window, {prevent_default:true} ).on("swiperight",function(event) { 
    if (myNavigator.getPages().length > 1) {
        myNavigator.popPage();
    }
 });
```

where the myNavigator is defined as

```
<ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator" page="page1.html">
</ons-navigator>
```

Note that in the above example, we do not use AngularJS's Controller and directly access the Navigator. This is a new feature of Onsen UI 1.1.0.

Comment: But will this follow the finger as the user swipes left? (Like a native view pop)

Comment: No, this is only a back action by swipe gesture.

Comment: Did OnsenUI originally support this?

Comment: Sorry, we have no plan to support this. If you have a good implementation, please tell us. Cheers.